# Ошибка в nginx 500 Internal Server Error (uwsgi + django) worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, http-status-code-500

Запуская связку nginx и uwsgi для запуска django проекта, столкнулся с ошибкой 500 на стороне nginx. Я залез в /var/log/nginx/error.log и нашел там конкретное название ошибки:

```
worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream ...
```

Я пробовал увеличить worker_connections в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, но при большом значении вылазить ошибка:

```
socket() failed (24: To many open files)
```

Пробовал решить это с помощью создания в том же /etc/nginx/nginx.conf параметра - worker_limit_nofile, но это возвращает ошибку worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream. Дальнейшая игра с увеличением, уменьшением этих двух параметров (worker_connections и worker_limit_nofile) ничего не дает. Мне лишь выкидывает то первую ошибку, то вторую.

В общем, пожалуйста, помогите избавиться от ошибок. Благодарю заранее! (прилагаю конфиги)

```
  GNU nano 4.8                 /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
#bilo auto
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;
events {
        worker_connections 20000;
        # 768 bilo tyt
        # multi_accept on;
}
...

  GNU nano 4.8           /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/eva/lawyer
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= lawyer.settings.production
wsgi-file = lawyer/wsgi.py
#module = lawyer.uwsgi:application
workers = 1
max-requests = 5000
#plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
#plugins = python3
#virtualenv = /root/eva/venv
home = /root/eva/venv
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
die-on-term = true
socket = /run/sedova.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = www-data
gui = www-data
```

GNU nano 4.8             /etc/nginx/conf.d/my_app.conf

```
server {
        listen 82;
        server_tokens off;
        server_name 185.46.8.164;
    
        #root /var/www/
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket;
            #
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            #
            proxy_pass http://185.46.8.164:82;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }...
```

VPS server on Linux (ubuntu 20.04)
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
uwsgi 2.0.20
python3
django 3.2.8

Comment: Эм, а нафига тут proxy_pass на самого себя. Так конечно никаких коннектов не хватит

Comment: Первый раз занимаюсь деплоем. Скажите, какой адрес указывать в прокси пас? Если я удаляю этот параметр, то выходит ошибка 502

Comment: Никакой. Он тебе вообще не нужен. У тебя uwsgi_pass есть для передачи запроса в джанго

Comment: Если убрать proxy_pass вылетает ошибка 502

Comment: И почему пути в socket и uwsgi_pass разные?

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал их одинаковыми

Answer (score 0):

Выражаю благодарность Alexey Ten!
Ошибка заключалась в конфиге
GNU nano 4.8 /etc/nginx/conf.d/my_app.conf

при замене             proxy_pass http://185.46.8.164:82;
на                     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;

ошибка 500 ушла и nginx запустился корректно.

Comment: Что? Какой proxy_pass?

Comment: Мне помогло это. Я писал вам ранее, что без этого параметра nginx выдает 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Конечно 502, раз у вас адрес был не тот. Нужно же хоть элементарную логику использовать

Comment: 502 выскакивает если убрать прокси пас даже с исправленными адресами